# Transaction failed when I had #[account(mut)]

Tags: anchor, solana-program

One of my function in my `lib.rs` was working until I add on of the account as mutable with `#[account(mut)]`.

This works:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(uuid:String)]
pub struct InitializeArticle<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer=user,
        space=10000,
        seeds = [uuid.as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub article: Account<'info, Article>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub seller_account: Account<'info, SellerAccount>,

    pub store: Account<'info, Store>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

However when I add `#[account(mut)]` to the `store` account I get an error, the function that use `InitializeArticle` struct is empty btw.

This does not work:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(uuid:String)]
pub struct InitializeArticle<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer=user,
        space=10000,
        seeds = [uuid.as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub article: Account<'info, Article>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub seller_account: Account<'info, SellerAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub store: Account<'info, Store>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

The error I get:
`Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete`

I don't know a way to debug because the error I get is not so precise about the origin of the issue.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Enclose your client code in a try..catch block and console.log the error. That'll give a more descriptive error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After putting my client code in a try..catch I got the following error:

```
Program failed to complete: Access violation in stack frame 5 at address 0x200005e58 of size 8 by instruction #16668
```

I tried Boxing my account structs, to move them to the heap and it solved my issue.